# Helpers en meteor

Tags: angularjs-2.0, meteor

Hola soy bastante nuevo en meteor y hace poco empecé mezclándolo con angular2. He intentado de todas las vías posibles hacer algo que me sea bastante parecido al populate en mongoose para obtener los objetos completos de las relaciones. Para esto he usado los paquetes de meteor `stfnbrgh:nested-collection-helpers` y `dburles:collection-helpers` pero cuando creo la collection de la siguiente manera

```
import {MongoObservable} from "meteor-rxjs";
export const Tasks=new MongoObservable.Collection('tasks');
```

Cuando intento hacer

```
Tasks.helpers({
  author(){
    Meteor.users.findOne(this.trabajador);
}
})
```

Me dice

> unresolved function or method helpers

Alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: cual es la version de tu **meteor**

Answer (score 0):

Los helpers en meteor deberian retornar algo intenta asi

```
return Meteor.users.findOne(this.trabajador);
```

ten en cuenta que si estas haciendo referencia this.trabajador este definida o la mandes como parametro al helper